# Unable to send client certificate while ssl connect to server

Tags: openssl

I am using quickfix to validate server's certificate and get fatal handshake_failure.

This is how it looks to me:

- Initial handshake is initiated
- The client connects.
- The server accepts.
- A TLS handshake occurs during which server requests for client certificates, which client fails to provide
- Cipher suites are successfully negotiated.
- The client verifies the server certificate
- The server arbitrarily closes the socket as client does not provide the certificate.
- The client is left hanging

Can someone take a look at it and guide how to send the client certificate along in handshake. Please.

**Client gets:**

```
*** CertificateRequest 
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA 
Cert Authorities:  <Empty> 
*** ServerHelloDone 
*** Certificate chain
```

**Server sees:**

```
SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE:peer did not return a certificate
```

Comment: If you _only_ need 'to validate server's certificate' you don't need to send a client cert and complete the handshake to do that; just get the chain from the server's first flight and validate it.